# html/javascript sharing script lists... or doing CI with jasmine and selenium

Tags: javascript, html, extjs, selenium, jasmine

I'm pretty new to js + html.  I've set up some (extjs) js based acceptance tests using jasmine and am now looking at getting continuous integration setup for them.

Because they run in browser, there's going to be a bit of mucking about to get them running under CI.  What I was thinking of doing was using selenium to run the tests (we've already got a working selenium setup so that should be easy) and using [jasmine-reporters](https://github.com/larrymyers/jasmine-reporters) to get the results output to a file that CruiseControl.net can understand.

Jasmine is pretty straight-forward in the way it works and you end up writing a html page that looks like this:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Jasmine Spec Runner v2.0.0</title>

<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="lib/jasmine-2.0.0/jasmine_favicon.png">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="lib/jasmine-2.0.0/jasmine.css">

<script type="text/javascript" src="lib/jasmine-2.0.0/jasmine.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="lib/jasmine-2.0.0/jasmine-html.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="lib/jasmine-2.0.0/boot.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    //set this a bit higher to aid debugging
    jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL = 20000;
</script>

<!-- include source files here... -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="Sample/src/Player.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Sample/src/Song.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="/native/WeatherVane.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/native/EventCreator.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="/ext/ext-all-dev.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/api/api.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    Ext.app.REMOTING_API.maxRetries = 0;
    Ext.direct.Manager.addProvider(Ext.app.REMOTING_API);
</script>

<!-- include spec files here... -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="Sample/spec/SpecHelper.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Sample/spec/PlayerSpec.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Tests/EventCreation.js"></script>

<!-- note this needs to be last as it fires up the tests-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="TestApp.js"></script>
```

I've not actually got round to stripping out the sample tests yet!
Anyway the easiest way I could see of doing this would be to another page which uses a different TestApp (the last entry) which configures jasmine to use the nunitreporter from the jasmine-reporters library and just get selenium to run that page

Obviously I dont want to just copy + paste everything in there and modify just the last bit.  This is going to be a list we're going to be adding to a lot and it's going to be a real pain if the CI and local testing aren't working basically the same way.

Basically what I'd like to do is effectively split it into two documents/sets of includes like this:

Document A - the shared setup

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Jasmine Spec Runner v2.0.0</title>

<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="lib/jasmine-2.0.0/jasmine_favicon.png">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="lib/jasmine-2.0.0/jasmine.css">

<script type="text/javascript" src="lib/jasmine-2.0.0/jasmine.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="lib/jasmine-2.0.0/jasmine-html.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="lib/jasmine-2.0.0/boot.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    //set this a bit higher to aid debugging
    jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL = 20000;
</script>

<!-- include source files here... -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="Sample/src/Player.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Sample/src/Song.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="/native/WeatherVane.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/native/EventCreator.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="/ext/ext-all-dev.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/api/api.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    Ext.app.REMOTING_API.maxRetries = 0;
    Ext.direct.Manager.addProvider(Ext.app.REMOTING_API);
</script>

<!-- include spec files here... -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="Sample/spec/SpecHelper.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Sample/spec/PlayerSpec.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Tests/EventCreation.js"></script>
```

Document B - the current browser output method:

```
 SomeCommandToInclude(documentA);

<!-- note this needs to be last as it fires up the tests-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="TestApp.js"></script>
```

Document C - the CI/xml output method:

```
 SomeCommandToInclude(documentA);

<!-- note this needs to be last as it fires up the tests-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="XmlOutputApp.js"></script>
```

I've felt myself wanting to do something very similar a few times with these html script lists.  How do you do this?  Is it even possible?  I was looking at some stuff to do with document.write a while ago but it didn't seem to do quite do the right thing.

If it's not possible to include these script lists in each other, I'm open to other approaches for getting the CI going, although I have a pretty strong preference for doing it with selenium as I dont want to learn yet another library/technology and spend ages fiddling to get it working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I did.  I didn't figure out how to include html files but I got something working.

**Basic approach**

I passed in a parameter in the url which says whether we are in CI mode.  The client side testing library parses the url to check if it should create xml output.  Because this is run in-browser by selenium it can't be saved directly to file.  Instead I wrote it into a string and then query this string from Selenium and from there write it out to disc.

**Jasmine-reporters**

Jasmine-reporters has been forked to cope with jasmine-2.0 which I am using **note that the 2.0 branch is not the main branch**.  I'm not familiar with git and was thrown by it hiding the other branch from you in the history.  There is a compatible version of jasmine-reporters there.

I used the NUnit reporter and to faciliate use with selenium I did a massive hack and replaced the write file method with the following:

```
    self.writeFile = function(text) {
        self.output(text, totalSpecsFailed > 0);
    };
```

I also added this to the constructor:

```
self.output = options.output;
```

My calling/config code then does this if we are in CI mode:

```
var jasmineEnv = jasmine.getEnv();
jasmineEnv.addReporter(new jasmineReporters.NUnitXmlReporter(
    {
        output: function (xmlOutput, anyFailures) {
            testConfig.xmlOutput = xmlOutput;
            testConfig.anyFailures = anyFailures;
        }
    }));
```

**Selenium**

The selenium code looks like this (note this isn't raw selenium - it's going through an API I've wrapped around the basic stuff but you should be able to get the gist)

```
    public void PokeTheTestPage()
    {
        try
        {
            NavigateTo(WebAppUrl + "Tests/Jasmine/SpecRunner.html?outputFile=true");

            var error = Driver.GetStringWith("return weatherVane.testConfig.errorText;");

            if (error != "")
                ExitWithError(error);

            var testOutput = LongWait.Until(d => d.GetStringWith("return weatherVane.testConfig.xmlOutput;"));
            var failed = Driver.GetBoolWith("return weatherVane.testConfig.anyFailures;");

            using (var file = File.OpenWrite(_outputFile))
            using (var writer = new StreamWriter(file))
                writer.Write(testOutput);

            if (failed)
                ExitWithError("tests failed");
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            ExitWithError(e.ToString());
        }
    }

    private void ExitWithError(string error)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("got Error:");
        Console.WriteLine(error);
        Driver.Close();
        Environment.Exit(1);
    }
}
```